# How to check the model against DB schema at startup

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, code-first

I have a caching database which can simply be dropped and re-created if there are missing new fields in the schema. I can't be bothered with Migrations, it always bugs me.

So how do I perform this startup check? `db.Database.CompatibleWithModel` returns true, but running a Linq query against a mismatched DataSet will throw an exception.

Most answers around this sort of thing point to Migrations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply test all DataSet possibilities using reflection:

```
try
{
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        //db.myDataSet.Take(0).SingleOrDefault(); //The following reflection achieves what this line would do
        var t = db.GetType();
        var props = t.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            if (!prop.PropertyType.Name.StartsWith("DbSet"))
                continue;
            var getMethod = prop.GetMethod;
            var dataSet = getMethod.Invoke(db, null);
            var dataSetType = dataSet.GetType();
            var queryableType = typeof(Queryable);
            var takeMethod = queryableType.GetMethod("Take");
            takeMethod = takeMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dataSetType.GenericTypeArguments);
            var takeResult = takeMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { dataSet, 0 });
            var sodMethod = queryableType.GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "SingleOrDefault" && m.GetParameters().Length == 1).Single();
            sodMethod = sodMethod.MakeGenericMethod(dataSetType.GenericTypeArguments);
            var finalResult = sodMethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { takeResult });
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.InnerException != null && ex.InnerException.InnerException.Message.StartsWith("Invalid column"))
    {
        MyHelperFunctions.MarkDatabaseForReset();
    }
    else
        throw; //Show error to user - we didn't expect this one
}
```

A little rough, but it worked for me. Plenty of scope for problems but should work 99% of the time (eg. all properties on a code-first datacontext are usually all DataSets)